# Как изменить размер подключаемого шрифта .ttf

Tags: qt

Подключил внешний шрифт.

```
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/DS-DIGIT.TTF");

QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
```

С помощью какого параметра можно изменять размер шрифта?

Comment: Сам нашел но вдруг кому надо 'font.setPointSize(14);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

два варианта:

- setPixelSize(int)
- setPointSize() или setPointSizeF()

setPixelSize делает шрифт зависимым от устройства. 
Используйте setPointSize() или setPointSizeF(), что бы установить размер шрифта не зависимым от устройства.